# ZF2 Executing DB query from Controller

Tags: php, sql, database, zend-framework2

Hi i am new to ZF2 and not familiar with some of the changes in ZF2. I would like to know how can i execute SQL query directly from Controller.

I have the following code:

```
 public function indexAction()
 {
    $db = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM books";
    $statement = $db->query($sql);
    $res =  $statement->execute();

    if($res instanceof ResultInterface && $res->isQueryResult()){
        $resultSet = new ResultSet;
        $resultSet->initialize($res);

        foreach($resultSet as $row){
            echo $row->title . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    exit;

    /*
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'books' => $this->getBooksTable()->fetchAll(),
    ));
    */
 }
```

When the controller above is opened in web browser, it does not show anything. If i echo "Blahh.." before the if statement, it displays the "Blahh.." text correctly.

Does anyone know why it does not display the query result properly? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

try to add this in the top of your controller :

```
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\ResultInterface;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
```